# Probability of sum of IID variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have $X_1, X_2$ two IID random variables and I know $P[X_1<\epsilon]=P[X_2<\epsilon]\le c$.

Can I claim that $P[X_1+X_2<2\epsilon]=P[X_1<\epsilon]\le c$

I'm confused as it seems right but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.
For example, consider tossing two fair dice, $X_1$ and $X_2$ the numbers appearing on the dice, and $\epsilon = 1.1$.
$$P(X_1 + X_2 \le 2.2) = P(X_1 + X_2 = 2) = \frac{1}{36}$$
while
$$P(X_1 < 1.1) = P(X_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{6} $$

Comment: Can I say anything about $P[X_1+X_2<2\epsilon]$ then?

Comment: $P(X_1 + X_2 < 2 \epsilon) \ge P(X_1 < \epsilon \ \text{and}\ X_2 < \epsilon) = P(X_1 < \epsilon)^2$.

Comment: In the other direction, $$\eqalign{P(X_1 + X_2 < 2 \epsilon) &\le P(X_1 < \epsilon \ \text{or}\ X_2 < \epsilon)\cr & = 2 P(X_1 < \epsilon) - P(X_1 < \epsilon)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuous example.

$X_1 \sim Exponential(1), X_2 \sim Exponential(1), Y = X_1+X_2, Y \sim Erlang(2,1)$ with $f_{Y}(y) = ye^{-y}$.

$$
P(X_1 < \varepsilon) = P(X_2 < \varepsilon) = 1-e^{-\varepsilon} \neq 1-(1+2 \varepsilon)e^{-2 \varepsilon} = P(Y \leq 2 \varepsilon)
$$